Solve the nonlinear system of algebraic equations
How to get steps of the solutions for:
        Solve[x^2 + 
            y^2 == (r - 65)^2 && (x - 85)^2 + (y + 185)^2 == (r - 
           55)^2 && (x - 150)^2 + (y + 45)^2 == (r - 35)^2, {x, y, r}]


One of ways is as follows. We start from
Expand[x^2 +  y^2 == (r - 65)^2 && (x - 85)^2 + (y + 185)^2 == (r - 
  55)^2 && (x - 150)^2 + (y + 45)^2 == (r - 35)^2]


x^2 + y^2 == 4225 - 130 r + r^2 &&  41450 - 170 x + x^2 + 370 y + y^2 == 3025 - 110 r + r^2 &&  24525 - 300 x + x^2 + 90 y + y^2 == 1225 - 70 r + r^2

We see x^2+y^2 in the second and third equations. We simplify those making use of the first equation.
Simplify[ 41450 - 170 x + x^2 + 370 y + y^2 == 3025 - 110 r + r^2 && 
24525 - 300 x + x^2 + 90 y + y^2 == 1225 - 70 r + r^2, 
Assumptions -> x^2 + y^2 == 4225 - 130  r + r^2]


2 r + 17 x == 4265 + 37 y && 4 (r + 5 x) == 1835 + 6 y

Now we can express x and y through r by solving a system of linear equations
Solve[2  r + 17 x == 4265 + 37 y && 4 (r + 5 x) == 1835 + 6  y, {x,  y}]


{x -> 1/638 (42305 - 136 r), y -> 1/638 (-54105 - 28 r)}}

At last, we substitute the above expressions in the first equation and solve it in r.
x^2 + y^2 == (r - 65)^2 /. {x -> 1/638  (42305 - 136  r),  y -> 1/638  (-54105 - 28  r)}


(42305 - 136 r)^2/407044 + (-54105 - 28 r)^2/407044 == (-65 + r)^2

Solve[(42305 - 136 r)^2/407044 + (-54105 - 28 r)^2/407044 == (-65 + r)^2, {r}, Reals]


{{r -> (11109660 - 1595 Sqrt[162728790])/193882}, {r -> ( 11109660 + 1595 Sqrt[162728790])/193882}}

The rest is left on your own.

Many thanks for very useful steps

Reduce on the equations works with back substitution:
eq = {x^2 + 
     y^2 == (r - 65)^2, (x - 85)^2 + (y + 185)^2 == (r - 
       55)^2, (x - 150)^2 + (y + 45)^2 == (r - 35)^2};
ans = {ToRules@Reduce[eq, {x, y, r}]};
a1 = ({x, y, r} /. ans[[1, {2, 3}]]) /. ans[[1, 1]]
a2 = ({x, y, r} /. ans[[2, {2, 3}]]) /. ans[[2, 1]]
N /@ {a1, a2}


Illustrating the solutions:
ctr = {{0, 0}, {85, -185}, {150, -45}};
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[eq /. r -> N[a1[[3]]]], {x, -300, 300}, {y, -300, 300}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[a1[[{1, 2}]]], Black, 
   Point[ctr]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[eq /. r -> N[a2[[3]]]], {x, -300, 300}, {y, -300, 300}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[a2[[{1, 2}]]], Black, 
   Point[ctr]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]




Many thanks, for plot.
